# How to make title bar progress bar a spin progress bar istead of horizontal bar?

Tags: android

I have created a activity and set a the title bar to contain a progress bar like this:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, 500);
```

But it turns out to be a horizontal bar, how can I make this a spin bar? (without creating a custom title bar)

Thanks, Jason

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);